# How to set Bitcoin-Qt setgenerate mining recipient?

Tags: bitcoin-core, miner-configuration

I know it's inefficient and a bad idea and all that, but I just discovered the `setgenerate` console command in Bitcoin-Qt (v0.8.1-beta, MAC) and I was wondering how to set the recipient address of "all those" Bitcoins I'm about to generate?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Bitcoin-QT will generate new addresses to mine to.  If you use the Encrypt Wallet feature, it appears to always mine to the same address instead, but it's still not user-selectable.

If you do want to CPU mine to a specific address (e.g. for testing on the RegTest mode), you can use mining software like [cpuminer/minerd](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=55038.0) in "solo mining" mode to do so.

Comment: Actually, it grabs an address out of the keypool. If it doesn't find a solution, it returns the address to the keypool.